# System.ArgumentException: 'Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <True> in BitTable_bit_col Column. Expected type is BitArray.'

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net, npgsql

I have the table in PostgreSQL, that consist of data type column BIT. I just using select command to get the results for my table using C# application.

When I am using Npgsql version [3.1.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/3.1.10),  then the DataTable load operation is working fine.

But if i am using Npgsql version [3.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/3.2.0) or above, then the DataTable load is failed with following error.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Type of value has a mismatch with column
>   typeCouldn't store  in BitTable_bit_col Column.  Expected type
>   is BitArray.'

Code snippet is below.

```
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;User Id=postgres;Password=root;Database=postgres;");
            conn.Open();

            var datatable = new DataTable();

            using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT \"BitTable\".\"id\" AS \"BitTable_id\"   ,\"BitTable\".\"bit_col\" AS \"BitTable_bit_col\"   ,\"BitTable\".\"boolean_col\" AS \"BitTable_boolean_col\" FROM \"BitTable\" AS \"BitTable\" limit 100", conn))
            {
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    datatable.Load(reader);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
```

I suspect that problem is in DataTable itself, surprisingly it can not read data properly. (In 3.1.10 version my datatype Bit column consider as Boolean, But in 3.2.0 version my datatype Bit column consider as BitArray. So, this issue occurs)

Please give any solution for me to resolve this issue in latest Npgsql version.